# Space of compactly supported function is NOT complete

Tags: functional-analysis, complete-spaces

> Claim: The space $C_c$ of real valued continuous, compactly supported functions is **not** complete

**Solution:**

I don't really know how to prove this claim. Nonetheless, I had some Ideas: I was able to prove that $C_c$ is not closed. Also we know that every complete subspace of a metric space is closed. But I cannot conclude. Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Contrapositive: If $C_c$ *were* complete, then by your lemma, you'd know it was closed. Since you claim to have shown that it's *not* closed, it must not be complete, and you're done. (I'm not claiming that this proof is correct, since I don't know whether you've really proved that it's not closed, etc.) Also: your assertion about complete subsets of metric spaces seems to be missing an important hypothesis. I think you should re-read that theorem.

Comment: You have to specify the topology you want to put on $C_c$. There are at least two popular ones, and with respect to one of them the space *is* complete...

Comment: @JohnHughes :  Sorry for the necropost. I thought the (counter?) example of $x^n$ on $[0,1]$ , which converges to a continuous function showed $C[a,b]$ was not complete in the Sup Norm . What am I missing? Is it not Cauchy?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't mention the norm for completion? but with the sup norm you may take a sequence  $f_n\in C_c$ converging to e.g. $1/(1+x^2)$ uniformly  (just truncate in a continuous way, not by indicator function). Then $f_n$ is Cauchy but does not converge in $C_c$.

Comment: Thank you @H.H.Rugh and sorry, indeed I meant the sup-norm!

Comment: what do you mean by "truncate in a continuous way"? How can we explicitly construct such a sequence of functions?

Comment: Yes, let $\phi(x)$ be a $C^\infty$ function with support e.g. in $[-2,2]$ and such that $\phi(x)=1$ for $|x|\leq 1$. Then the sequence $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \phi(x/n)$, $n\geq 1$ has the wanted properties.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh: Sorry for necropost.  Any idea what is its completion? I mean Cc under the Sup norm.

Comment: @MSIS  The completion is $C_0({\Bbb R})$  the space of continuous functions that tend to zero at infinity (as is fairly easy to see).

Answer (score 2):

You are missing something in the statement you propose to use. The complete subspace should namely be a subspace of a *complete* metric space. Thus:

> A subspace of a complete metric space is closed if, and only if, it is complete.

I guess you consider $C_c$ as a subspace of the space of continuous functions? If so, then this space is complete with respect to the supremum norm. You can finish your proof then as follows:

> Suppose towards a contradiction that $C_c$ is complete. Then, according to the above statement, the space $C_c$ is closed in the space of continuous functions. A contradiction, which implies that $C_c$ cannot be complete.

Comment: yes $C_c$ is a subspace of the space of continuous functions!

Answer (score 1):

@ H. H. Rugh has the answer. The bell-shaped function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|^2}$ he mentioned asymptotically vanishes at infinity. Then pick a large $[-n,+n], \ n \in \mathbb{N}$ and via a short line segment, continuously join the ends of the function to the $x$-axis, so that you get a continuous, and now compactly supported function.

But if $n$ is larger and larger, then your truncations will infinitely closely approximate your original function. They themselves will form a Cauchy sequence. Since $f$ is not compactly supported, this sequence negates completeness of the space.

Comment: Yes :) Thanks. But you know, there is an intimate relation between completeness and compactness.